# AQL how to return entire document instead of single item of document

Tags: arangodb, aql

Below is the AQL Query.

```
for doc in `managed-function`
  collect mkey = doc.mkey
  return mkey
```

Above query returns only unique mkey list.
I want the entire doc to be returned, how can I achieve it ?

Comment: The question is unclear to me - what do you want to get if there is more than one document with a given mkey? A list of all Documents, or just one - if so: which one? Can you provide a simple small example of source and target data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `INTO` clause to the `COLLECT` operation, like this for example:

```
for doc in `managed-function`
  collect mkey = doc.mkey into docs = doc
  return {mkey, docs}
```

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-collect.html#grouping-syntaxes

Comment: Now with your changes I am able to receive doc(s) but problem is collect should give all distinct doc(s) but it is not. How can we resolve this ? 

Below is Sample Doc 
<START>
 { "_key": "e9152844-766e-44e3-96bc-0ebd8807f7a2", "_id": "managed-function/e9152844-766e-44e3-96bc-0ebd8807f7a2", "x2u-local-gtp-port": 7, "mkey": "cu:10000:1", "cu-host-name": "ENB2", "xnodeb-id": 10000, } 
<END>
key, id , mkey are individual elements of a doc.

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct doc(s)"? Every document is distinct and unique because it contains a unique `_key`. The query groups by `mkey`, and for every unique `mkey` value, it returns that key as well as the full documents having that value. I think you should ask a new question for this, with more complete examples of your data and the expected result.